# Get the Latitude and Longitude from address

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am planning to use this following subroutine in asp.net web application to get the Latitude and Longitude from the given address (any address in the world). For an example, on saving vendor details, the system will show the map with exact Latitude and Longitude.

We are planning to use google map in our web application. I believe I am using version 3 of google API which has a limit of 2500 requests per day.

Could you please advise me if there is any other efficient way of getting the Latitude and Longitude from any world address? Also is there any API which has no request limits and can be used with google.

Also do i need to sign up for google APIv3?

**Code:**

```
Private Sub GetLatLongFromAddress(street As String, city As String, zipcode As String, state As String)

    Dim geocoderUri As String = String.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0},{1},{2},{3}&sensor=false", street, city, zipcode, state)

    Dim geocoderXmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
    geocoderXmlDoc.Load(geocoderUri)

    Dim nsMgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(geocoderXmlDoc.NameTable)
    nsMgr.AddNamespace("geo", "http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#")

    Dim sLong As String = geocoderXmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//geometry/location/lat", nsMgr).InnerText
    Dim sLat As String = geocoderXmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//geometry/location/lng", nsMgr).InnerText

    txtLat.Text = sLat
    txtLon.Text = sLong
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that you have to sign up to use the API

Comment: Is there any free API to get the Latitude and Longitude?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks like you're doing the basic actions, and I don't believe you can do it more efficient. Geocoding is an intensive process.

To answer your other questions:

- No you don't need to register to use the API, but it is advised.
  Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/signup
- The free license is restricted to 2500 request per 24 hours. The only
  way to get around it is to get a Google Maps API for Business
  licence, which is paid and moves the limit up to 100k requests. Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing

NOTE: Google explicitly states that you may not use the geocoding services without using Maps.

Comment: Can i get the geocode from other open source API's and then show the results on google map?

Comment: Yes, you can place a marker on the map by sending a lat and lon to the API, so it doesn't matter where you got the coordinates from. I found this small tutorial to do so: http://www.sitepoint.com/google-maps-api-jquery/